# Is it okay to get a Reference Letter from a PhD holder with years of experience in a related field that is not a Professor?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

Is it okay to get a Reference Letter from a PhD holder with years of experience in a related field that is not a Professor and can speak well of me because he/she was my undergrad thesis supervisor?

Answer (score 2):

Letters of recommendation are not restricted to professors (unless directions specifically require that).

Someone who has a PhD who acted as your research supervisor should be qualified to make a judgment about your potential as a researcher, which is usually what admissions committees are interested in when they review applications.

Comment: I don't think it's *obvious* that just anyone with a PhD can judge someone's potential as a researcher.

Comment: @JiK And that is not what is being claimed in this answer either.